# Running zipWithIndex() on Spark cluster in ec2 fails with 'Network is unreachable'

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run an application from my workstation (inside Intellij) and connect to a remote Spark cluster (2.3.1) running on ec2. I know this isn't a best practice, but if I can get this to work for development it will make my life a lot easier.

I've managed to get fairly far, and I am able to run operations on RDDs and return results, until I get to a step which uses .zipWithIndex() and I get the following exception:

```
ERROR 2018-07-19 11:16:21,137 o.a.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher  Exception while beginning fetch of 1 outstanding blocks 
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /172.x.x.x:33898
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:245) ~[spark-combined-shaded-2.3.1-evg1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:187) ~[spark-combined-shaded-2.3.1-evg1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService$$anon$2.createAndStart(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:113) ~[spark-combined-shaded-2.3.1-evg1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.fetchAllOutstanding(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:141) [spark-combined-shaded-2.3.1-evg1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.start(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:121) [spark-combined-shaded-2.3.1-evg1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService.fetchBlocks(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:123) [spark-combined-shaded-2.3.1-evg1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.spark.network.BlockTransferService.fetchBlockSync(BlockTransferService.scala:98) [spark-combined-shaded-2.3.1-evg1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getRemoteBytes(BlockManager.scala:691) [spark-combined-shaded-2.3.1-evg1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$3$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(TaskResultGetter.scala:82) [spark-combined-shaded-2.3.1-evg1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$3$$anonfun$run$1.apply(TaskResultGetter.scala:63) [spark-combined-shaded-2.3.1-evg1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$3$$anonfun$run$1.apply(TaskResultGetter.scala:63) [spark-combined-shaded-2.3.1-evg1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1991) [spark-combined-shaded-2.3.1-evg1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$3.run(TaskResultGetter.scala:62) [spark-combined-shaded-2.3.1-evg1.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_172]
```

where 172.x.x.x is the (censored) local IP inside the AWS VPC of the spark instance containing both the master and worker. I have configured the ec2 Spark instance so that it should be using it's public DNS with `SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS` and use the following configuration to build my SparkContext:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
              .setAppName("myapp")
              .setMaster(System.getProperty("spark.master", "spark://ec2-x-x-x-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7077"))
              .set("spark.cores.max", String.valueOf(4))
              .set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
              .set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", String.valueOf(maxResultSize))
              .set("spark.executor.memory", "2G")
              .set("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-XX:+UseG1GC")
              .set("spark.ui.retainedStages", String.valueOf(250))
              .set("spark.ui.retainedJobs", String.valueOf(250))
              .set("spark.network.timeout", String.valueOf(800))
              .set("spark.driver.host", "localhost")
              .set("spark.driver.port", String.valueOf(23584))
              .set("spark.driver.blockManager.port", String.valueOf(6578))
              .set("spark.files.overwrite", "true")
              ;
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate();
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());
jsc.addJar("my_application.jar");
```

And then I make an SSH tunnel with

```
ssh -R 23584:localhost:23584 -L 44895:localhost:44895 -R 27017:localhost:27017 -R 6578:localhost:6578 ubuntu@ec2-x-x-x-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

so that the workers can see back to my machine. What am I missing? Why is there still an attempt to connect to something by it's AWS IP that can't be seen from my machine?

Edit: When I look at the web UI I can see that the port referenced in  `java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /172.x.x.x:33898` does indeed belong to an executor. How can I tell my driver to connect through the public IP rather than the private IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was eventually able to solve this by setting the undocumented variable SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME to the public DNS in my spark-env.sh file.

My environment configuration now looks like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
export SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS="ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
export SPARK_MASTER_HOST=""
export SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME="ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
```